# Text over an image not working

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using this method.
https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

In the wordpress css file i added this code

```html
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px; 
}

h2 span.spacer {
   padding:0 5px;
}
```

After saving the css file i make a new post with this code

```html
<div class="image">

      <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg" alt="" />
      
      <h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>

</div>
```

Bu it does not work the image gets displayed and text is displayed at the bottom and not over the image

Comment: seems to work in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r4n6or2v/1/

Comment: I have tried these the also dont work for me in wordpress  css-tricks.com/design-considerations-text-images/

Comment: You didn't add the spans like the example does. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mx2jh081/

Comment: Of course copying and pasting this straight into a worpress site might not with properly as you will have other things effecting images and header in your wordpress theme. You need to contain it within its own area

Comment: Ok now it works but I don't see the text inside that blakish box like the one which is shown here https://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Answer (score 1):

The line that reads `<h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>` should read 
`<h2><span>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</span></h2>`

Please see this: https://jsfiddle.net/r4n6or2v/3/